# Working outside of application context when using flask_api_key

Tags: python, flask, api-key

Based on https://pypi.org/project/flask-api-key/ I am trying to implement:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_api_key import APIKeyManager, api_key_required

app = Flask(__name__)

my_key_manager = APIKeyManager(app)
my_key_manager.create("First_key")

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "hi Home"

@app.route("/protected")
@api_key_required
def protected():
    return "hi protected"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Error message:**

> "RuntimeError: Working outside of application context. This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
> to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
> this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
> documentation for more information."

Answer (score 0):

A Flask app context can be created as a Python context manager:

```py
with app.app_context():
    my_key_manager.create("my_first_key")
```

See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/appcontext/ if you want background information about what the app context is.

NB, when running an updated version of your code, I then hit another issue with the flask_api_key library, which looks like this issue: https://github.com/jthop/flask-api-key/issues/2

Comment: Yes I hit that issue too